# Enter into Gentoo and execute gentoo commands like equery

Tags: linux, shell, gentoo

I have written a shell script to enter into gentoo prefix and run commands.
But once it enters in Gentoo prefix it stops and doesn't execute rest of the steps. According to me console has changed from RHEL to GENTOO which is preventing shell script from executing rest of commands.
Is there any way that without entering in GENTOO prefix I can execute gentoo specific commands in shell script?

Commands used :

```
Gentoo_prefix
equery list > file.csv
```

Script :

```
cat file | awk '{print $3}'| cut -d '/' -f3 | cut -d '_' -f1 | sort -u | uniq -u | sed 's/.$//' > files
read -n 2 Detail
files=`echo $Detail | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]'`
read server
Server=`echo $server | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]'`
for nat in $(cat files)
do
    for serv in $Server
    do
        if [ $files == $nat -a $Server == $serv ]
        then
            ls /tmp/$nat'0_'$serv/ | grep -i python > module
            read module_name
            ls /tmp/$nat'0_'$serv/$module_name/ | grep ^3 > version
            $version_name = ' '
            read version_name
            for name in $(cat version)
            do
                if [ $version_name == ' ' ]
                    for pack in $(cat module)
                    do
                        if [ $version_name == $pack ]
                        then
                            $version_name
                            equery list > components.csv
```

Comment: We can't help you if you don't post the script.

Comment: Post it in the question so it can be formatted readably.

Comment: Please check question now I have posted the script as well. once $version_name line is executed, it enters into Gentoo and next line is not executed.

Comment: FYI, you don't need `uniq -u` after `sort -u`, since `sort -u` doesn't output duplicates.

Comment: okay will remove that but could you please help me in out in gentoo?

Comment: I don't understand `if [ $files == $nat -a $Server == $serv ]`. `$Server` is the whole list of servers, while `$serv` is the current one in the loop. How can they be the same, unless there's only one server in the list?

Comment: its just a draft script which I just modified to remove few confidential details!!

Comment: What do you mean by "help out in gentoo"? Gentoo is a Linux distribution, not an application.

Comment: and yeah you are right only one server detail is there in the list at a time, the original script is working fine till entering into gentoo prefix..once it enters in gentoo prefix it throws login details on console and stops!

Comment: Where is `gentoo_prefix` in the script?

Comment: $version_name ...bootstrap-prefix.sh is installed and named as different version like 3.2 3.3!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to feed input to a command in a script, you have to pipe to it or use a here-doc, not just put the input after the command like you would if you were typing it interactively.

```
                    if [ $version_name == $pack ]
                    then
                        echo 'equery list > components.csv' | $version_name
```

or

```
                    if [ $version_name == $pack ]
                    then
                        $version_name <<EOF
equery list > components.csv
EOF
```

Comment: echo equery list | $version_name  > components.csv this also works along with echo 'equery list > components.csv' | $version_name Thanks!